# Emacs smart tabs mode formatting with function parameters

Tags: emacs, indentation

Smart tabs mode is supposed to use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment.
Here is a picture of what it is currently doing:
[image: Current smart tabs mode]

In my mind this appears to be backwards, the spaces should precede the tabs because the tabs are alignment relative to the anonymous function on the `dosomething();` line.

Is there some tweak to smart tabs mode to behave like that, or am I off base?

Comment: A tab char that follows space chars has the visual effect of "swallowing" them - just enough of them to move to the next tab stop.

Comment: @Drew Sure, but that is a view interpretation choice, not a semantic choice.

Comment: All smart tabs really does is set `indent-tabs-mode` to `t` and make `tab-width` very large while running the normal indentation code.  This has the effect of If the normal indentation code (which is more or less independent for each major mode) doesn't know how to semantically indent the code, smart tabs won't either.  I understand what you want, but I don't think it will work without hacking on whatever major mode you're using.